# Regex to detect multiple repetitions

Tags: python-3.x, regex, data-extraction

I have unstructured data where I have to extract BP values as shown below. Right now I have a regex function to extract Bp values. I have a specific case as highlighted in the picture where consecutive values are present and they have to be detected.

Currently, the code I have gives only the 1st value.

I have attached the regex code below.

```
regex = \b(?:BP:?(?:-Sitting)?|Blood Pressure) \d+/\d+(?: mmHg?)?|B/P - (?:Sys|Dias)tolic \d+|(?:Sys|Dias)tolic Blood Pressure \d+ \w+\b
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!
[image]

The current output I am getting is - BP 128/80

Expected Output is - BP 128/80 128/81 128/82 128/83

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/nrntL2/1

Comment: Please refrain from posting images of text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optionally repeat the part that matches the values with the forward slash

```
\b(?:BP:?(?:-Sitting)?|Blood Pressure) \d+/\d+(?: \d+/\d+)*(?: mmHg?)?|B/P - (?:Sys|Dias)tolic \d+|(?:Sys|Dias)tolic Blood Pressure \d+ \w+\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nrntL2/1/)

Comment: Damn! I am amazed at how quickly you guys find a solution to these!!